# Change one button color when onPress in list

Tags: react-native

So i want to make a list with a heart button
when i tap on one heart button.

i want only one button changed color.
and save the current button color state.

My Problem is 
When i tap on one heart button, all button changed color.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**this is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import Data from './src/data/sampledata.json';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      buttonColor: '#979797', // default button color goes here, grey is default
    };
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    if(this.state.buttonColor=='#ff002b')
    {
      this.setState({ buttonColor: '#979797' }) // grey
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ buttonColor: '#ff002b' }) // red
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          Data.map((item, i) => (
            <ListItem
              key={item.index}
              title={item.dataItem}
              rightIcon={
                <Icon
                raised
                name='heart'
                type='font-awesome'
                color={this.state.buttonColor}
                onPress={this.onButtonPress}
              />
            }
            />
          ))
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

Comment: So one solution could be to move the icon into it's own component and then use setState locally

Comment: Create custom component and give it to `ListItem` for render , Basis on that change your current item view instead whole `ListItem`.

Comment: I am Glad you got it working. Cheers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this is as follows:

What you can do is keep track of the selected items in an array. Using `getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray` function you can get an array that contains all the selected item like so

```
const getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray = (selectedItems, id) => {
    const forDeletion = [id]; //can also be used for multiple ids
    if (selectedItems.includes(id)) {
        //if id already exists delete it
        return selectedItems.filter(item => !forDeletion.includes(item));
    } 
    //otherwise push it
    selectedItems.push(id);
    return selectedItems;
};
```

you can call the above function from `this.onButtonPress(item)` which takes `item` as an argument.

```
//Creating state

this.state = {
      buttonColor: '#979797', 
      selectedItems: []
};
```

Calling `getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray()` will give you updated array which you can set in your selectedItems state.

Lastly you will have check while giving the color to icon(item), that if item.id exists in `this.state.selectedItems` then show red otherwise grey, like so

```
Data.map((item, i) => (
            <ListItem
              key={item.index}
              title={item.dataItem}
              rightIcon={
                <Icon
                raised
                name='heart'
                type='font-awesome'
                color={this.checkIfIDExists(item.id) ? 'red' : 'grey'}
                onPress={this.onButtonPress}
              />
            }
            />
))
```

P.S `this.checkIfIDExists(item.id)` is a function the returns `true` if id exists in selectedItems array.